# How to add a PWD in to .env

Tags: bash, shell

Is there anyway to use `pwd` or $PWD in .env. Im looking to get the PWD so that I can add it to an `PYTHONPATH` env.

Thanks,

Comment: Must the overridden PYTHONPATH be in the `.env` file? As opposed to running your python instance with something like `PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${PWD} python`

Answer (score 0):

`.env` files in almost every language are hard-coded and not interpreted. @Tyler Stoney's suggestion is a better approach if you need a dynamic env variable available at runtime.

You could write a simple bash function to do this for you dynamically:

```
function py() {
  PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:$PWD" python $@
}
```

Then you could just run `py [script.py]`

> Note: If you try to do this in an alias instead, it will cache the
> contents of $PWD into the alias so a function is needed instead.